# how to report android app crash log after deployment to production version

Tags: android

My android app is crash after deployment to production. we implementd crash log report to send hockey by asking user to send with prompt dialog . Problem is that after crash occurs, app cannot launch and activity cannot start. So prompt cannot show and user cannot send crash report.

Comment: Use Firebase crash reporting. Its much better. :)

Comment: I am using Fabrics it's working fine.

Comment: Is your apk signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple option which you can implement but you need to analyze according to your needs  :

Option 1 : Firebase :

You can gr thruough this link which give a detailed explaination of integrating the firebase crash reporting. Its easy and can be done in not more than 1 hour

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-from-scratch-firebase-crash-reporting--cms-27167

Option 2 : Crashlytics : You can go through the documentation to integrate the same on the below link

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

There are other crash reporting tools such as appdynamics, as well but I prefer using above two for my projects. In case you need to see more option go through this link https://appsamurai.com/7-crash-reporting-tools-for-ios-and-android-apps/

here is a comparision for both of them

[Crash Firebase vs Crashlytics vs HockyApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498120/crash-firebase-vs-crashlytics-vs-hockyapp)

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/firebase-crash-reporting-vs-crashlytics-a6c287c4b792

Answer (score 1):

You can either use some crashlytic tool like `Fabric` to track crashes automatically or you can yourself handle `UncaughtExceptions` in your project and prompt user an alert, when ever a crash happens, to submit a bug report.

**Put the following code in Application class of your project**

```
/**
 * To catch all unCaught Exception.
 */
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler unCaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
      // show an alert to user to submit a bug report or do some other stuff
    }


};
```

**And in `onCreate` meathod of Application class do the following**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(unCaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```